# Html div element issue

Tags: html, css

I have a div into which I insert a triangle image using ::after see in image below 
[image: Div with triangle image using ::after]

If digits are increased in the brackets the div moves to the left but I want to fix it in the center. How can I do this?

I was trying the following code

```
.popup::after {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("drp_arw.png") no-repeat scroll center 0;
   bottom: -25px;
   content: "";
   height: 25px;
   left: 450px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide complete html and css code for the block in your image. You can also create a sample on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: We need complete code but I guess that the length of the element with the number in () brackets is pushing the `::after`

Comment: actually its an popup works on hover, and the values are coming dynamically so i just fix that triangle position if digits are increase like (0),(01),(012) and more in all cases that triangle should be in center.

Comment: Share the code of the box, `::after` here is not relevant.

Comment: <div class="popup"> 
 <div class="sub-popup">
  <h3>Some content here<h3>
  <p>Some content here</p>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: CSS code                                                                                      .popup 
{
    display: none;
}
.sub-popup 
{
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #bbb;
    left: -35px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.sub-popup::after 
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("drp_arw.png") no-repeat scroll center 0;
    bottom: -25px;
    content: "";
    height: 25px;
    left: 450px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
}

Comment: please see on http://jsfiddle.net/pkwd/4na8ujvk/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/46eh1hf7/1/
`::after` element is as long as parent so centred background make sure arrow stays in correct place.

Edit:
Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/4na8ujvk/4/ It's not perfect but maybe will be useful.

Comment: Thanks Volvox, but my problem still pending because the values are increase under given (0),(012) brackets and the popup works hover on brackets.

Comment: Basically the bracket values are increase in that case i want bottom triangle in center whatever values like (0),(01),(012...) and more.

Comment: @P.K i've added new example

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: volvox, its useful but i am not getting proper output as per image i given.

Comment: @P.K I'm confused. In my example popup has arrow in middle which is pointing middle of number. How you wanted it? Which elements should move and which stay in place? On your image popup has arrow in middle and it is pointing first digit of number.

Comment: @Paulie_D I think this does not apply here, as mine links are direct answers to specific problem, not links to page somewhat connected to problem. But I admit - I should add some more explanation to answer.

Comment: @Volvox, yes i want arrow in middle the content under bracket that is dynamic so i want stay div position with that arrow in center if the becoming digits are one, two or more in a given bracket

Comment: Hello everyone, please resolve my problem given above i didn't got solution still.